# Shortest Path Length as mathematical function/expression

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, linear-programming

I have a graph (unweighted and undirected) of n vertices. My objective is to express the following constraints as inequalities.

1. The degree of any node should be at least 3.
2. The shortest path length between any two nodes should be at most 5.

I have an adjacency matrix $X$.

> $Xij = 1$, if $i$ and $j$ are directly connected,
>
> $0$ otherwise

Now, I have expressed constraint 1 as

> $\sum_j X_{ij} \ge 3$

that is for every node $i$, the row-wise sum should be at least $3$

I don't know how to express the constraint 2 in terms of $X_{ij}$.
if $f(X)$ is the shortest path length, $f(X) \le 5$ is the constraint. But what is $f(X)$, the mathematical function for shortest path length ?

---

Comment: the only thing i can think about is $X^n_{ij}$ is the number of $i \to j$ paths of length exactly $n$

Answer (score 1):

gt6989b's comment goes most of the way towards solving your problem. The number of paths from $i$ to $j$ of length $m$ is $(X^m)_{ij}$, so the number of paths from $i$ to $j$ of length at most $m$ is $\left(\sum_{k=0}^mX^k\right)_{ij}$. In your case, all these entries should be positive for $m=5$, so you want

$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^5X^k\right)_{ij}=\left(\frac{1-X^6}{1-X}\right)_{ij}\gt0\quad\text{for all}\quad1\le i,j\le n\;
$$

(where the expression in the middle is defined unless the adjacency matrix has an eigenvalue $1$).